# Should I offer a Job in another company to my current colleague who is leaving?

Tags: job-offer, politics

Recently, there was a fallout between my manager and one of my colleagues. The circumstances regarding the fallout was childish and based on non-work related stuff. After some exchanges between these two about some manners in work environment and some harsh words from both sides, my manager waited for some apology and when he didn't get any, he decide to end contract of this colleague starting next month and she must leave after that.

I tried to meddle in this argument and talked with both parties to cool down the situation (I'm the supervisor of the team) but due to the refusal of apology from the colleague and insistence of manager to get apology, nothing really happened. Now it got to the point of no return and all the forms from HR signed and I can call my colleague, and ex-colleague.

In the mean time, one of my friends looking for the exact same position for their company. Their company is a competitor but we don't have any non-transferable of staff rules. This friend is also a ex-colleague who got terminated under the same manager 2 years ago (due to work-related stuff). he asked me if I know anyone who's looking for job in my team or anywhere else. now I don't know what to do. I want my colleague to find work for her sake. I don't get anything in this case. I just doing this for good deeds.

If I forward this offer to my out going colleague, it may result in complication and she "MAY" use it in her ongoing dispute with my manager (I already found a job through your own supervisor discussion) or maybe implies that maybe I lead the colleague to the point of no return and it will paint me as unreliable.

The question is: Should I forward the offer to my colleague ? and should my manager knows about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first take is that is that you are somewhat messing with fire that may burn you when you choose to meddle in situations like this. By involving yourself in the middle of the dispute you could find any number of things that could get pinned on you, whether justified or not.

If you do want to refer this person to the opening at your friends other company there are a number of things to consider:

1. You should consider whether your colleague has a tendency to get involved in childish arguments often. If so you will have to decide if your friend at the other company wants deal with that.
2. The best time to make the referral would be when your colleague is completely out the door and disconnected from the current company.
3. Being that you have already gotten into the middle of this dispute you will likely have to explain to your colleague that they need to let go of any continuing animosity toward the manager and not try to continue to fuel the fire with more pokes and barbs. If that leads to the colleague sucking things up and making an apology to the manager so much the better.